# Find events within a month and year

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

Let's say I have a event schema below

```
eventSchema = new Schema({
 name: { type: String },
 startDate: {type: Date },
 endDate: {type: Date }
});
```

And I have a set of data:

```
  { name: 'Event 1'
    startDate: '2017-06-23 09:58:03.759Z'
    endDate: '2017-07-02 09:58:03.759Z'
  },
  { name: 'Event 2'
    startDate: '2017-07-05 09:58:03.759Z'
    endDate: '2017-07-10 09:58:03.759Z'
  }
  { name: 'Event 3'
    startDate: '2017-07-23 09:58:03.759Z'
    endDate: '2017-08-01 09:58:03.759Z'
  }
  { name: 'Event 4'
    startDate: '2017-08-03 09:58:03.759Z'
    endDate: '2017-08-05 09:58:03.759Z'
  }
```

How to write a query to find the events that occurred within 2017-07-01 to 2017-07-31?

Which means I need to get the data set of Event 1, 2 and 3.

Here is what I done so far:

```
Event.find({
  $and: [
    { startDate: { $gte: start } },
    { endDate: { $lte: end } },
    ]
  }, (err, events) => {
    if (err) return next(err);;
    res.send({ success: true, events: events });
  });
```

Comment: It's simply the other way around `Event.find({ "startDate": { "$lt": end }, "endDate": { "$gt": start } })` Presuming `var start = new Date("2017-07-01"), end = new Date("2017-08-01");` And you really "should" be using the start time of the new month and `$lt` to cover time properly. This is almost really an interview question and there should be duplicate questions of this sitting around.

Comment: Also note that **ALL** MongoDB condtions are already **AND** conditions. You very rarely actually need to write `$and` explicitly, and it's "array" syntax is there so you can do things on the same named keys.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, Cool! It works. Thank you for your help. I do agreed that my question is almost an interview question. I am still learning mongodb query.

Comment: I actually have used pretty much the same thing "as an interview question". Because it's a basic distillation of the logic that the "start" comes "before" the "end" of the range and the "end" comes "after" the "start" of the range. Now you know if someone else asks you in an interview.